# Spring application properties file not taking in tomcat in windows envt

Tags: java, linux, spring, tomcat, window

While deploying Spring application in Apache tomcat version 7 getting below error in Windows,But in the same application working in linux environment.
The properties files are in webapps/{contextname}/WEB-INF/classes in both environment.

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in
>   com.org.app.web.config.DatabaseConfig: Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type
>   [java.util.Properties]: No qualifying bean of type
>   [java.util.Properties] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean
>   which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency
>   annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=hibernateProperties)};
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [java.util.Properties] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=hibernateProperties)}

Please help me to solve this

The code snippet attached below

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class WebConfig {

 }

@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
@Qualifier("hibernateProperties") final Properties props) { 

 }

  @DevelopmentProfile
    @FullProfile
    @Bean(name = "hibernateProperties")
    public Properties additionalProperties() {
}
```

Comment: you are trying to autowire a bean called "hibernateProperties" but this bean is not declared. I suggest to you to check your configuration

Comment: "hibernateProperties " bean is already declared in the config class